# Synchronous GET request with YUI 2.7?

Tags: javascript, yui, callback, request, synchronous

i'm relatively new to YUI - browsing their great docs, i do not find a method or a flag to load an external resource **synchronously**.

or the question the other way around; for each matched node i need to call a method, which inserts something at the node; with asynchronous calls the *remembered* *identifiers* seem to mess up.

therefore the callback need to stick to the

```
pid
```

when the function is called, not when the callback gets executed - am i getting this right?

```
var platform_ids = YAHOO.util.Selector.query('.platform_id'); 

for (var i = 0; i < platform_ids.length; i++) {
    var pid = platform_ids[i].getAttribute("id");
    var sUrl = "/platform/" + pid + "/description/";
    var callback = { success: function(o) { 
        document.getElementById(pid).innerHTML =  o.responseText; }}
    var transaction = YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest(
        'GET', sUrl, callback, null
    );
}
```

thanks.
MYYN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want a synchronous request. The user experience can be awful. You really just want to pass a value to your callback so that it's not relying on `pid` (which, as you've noticed, will usually have a different value when your callback is called):

```
var callback = { success: function(o) 
  { 
    document.getElementById(o.argument).innerHTML =  o.responseText; 
  }, 
  argument: pid
};
```

Here, I use the `argument` callback member to hold the ID, and reference that in the callback function itself, ensuring each callback uses the correct ID.

Comment: yes, i just found the part in the docs ;) your code worked; thanks!